# Convolution of PDFs is a PDF

Tags: probability, proof-verification, random-variables

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are PDFs of real-valued random variables. Show that the convolution $f\ast g$ of $f$ and $g$ (defined below) is also a PDF.
>   $$(f\ast g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)g(x-y)\,dy.$$

Firstly, I am not certain exactly what I need to show. In the text, we started with a random variable and defined from that the PDF, and then observed that it had the property that its integral over $\Bbb{R}$ was $1$. For this reason I am thinking that if I can show $\int_\Bbb{R} (f\ast g)(x)\,dx=1$, then I will be done.

Would the following be sufficient to prove that the convolution is a PDF?
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)g(x-y)\,dy\,dx 
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x-y)\,dx\bigg)\,dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\cdot1\,dy =1,
\end{align}
Using that $f$ and $g$ are PDFs in the bottom line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct. You just need to justify the change in order of integration using [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions) (the integrand is non-negative).

Comment: Ahh thanks. And I guess I should also remark that the convolution is non-negative, as that's a necessary property of PDFs